# Solution of a system of two congruences with two unknowns (both congruences with the same modulo)

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

Make an algorithm in Python for a solution of a system of two congruences with two unknowns - 2 congruences has the same modulo(n). The program should return a message as to whether the system has one solution, it has many, or not at all.

```
{ +  ≡  (mod n)
{ +  ≡  (mod n)
```

a,b,c,d,e,f,n input by console

I can't develop an algorithm for two congruences. I found on the internet only for a single congruence. Could someone please help?

Comment: can you do it by hand? If so, simply break the solution into fine-grained steps that you need to do and just write them as statements.

Comment: I cant the solution of substituting all possible division remainders by  as  and .

Comment: If it wasn't mod n then how would you solve it? Now what changes when you make it mod n? What if it was mod p, where p is a prime? Head over to wikipedia and look up modular inverses and the chinese remainder theorem.